# CloudFlare switching between non-fully-qualified and fully-qualified domain names; is this normal?

Tags: domains, dns, cloudflare

Over the past day or so, I've started seeing CloudFlare randomly oscillating its DNS responses between the FQDNs and non-FQDNs for my domain, as follows:

```
"Question": [
    {
        "name": "subdomain.example.com.",
        "type": 5
    }
],
"Authority": [
    {
        "name": "example.com.",
        "type": 6,
        "data": ...
    }
],
```

and

```
"Question": [
    {
        "name": "subdomain.example.com",
        "type": 5
    }
],
"Authority": [
    {
        "name": "example.com",
        "type": 6,
        "data": ...
    }
],
```

These are responses for `subdomain.example.com`, requested via a simple GET request (with Accept: application/dns-json) to `https://cloudflare-dns.com/dns-query?name=subdomain.example.com&type=CNAME`.

I'm not really sure why this is happening or how I should react. Is this normal behavior? Are both responses correct? Should I be concerned about this (especially potential correctness or security ramifications)? Is there something I can/should be doing to avoid this?

Comment: A name without a trailing dot can still by fully qualified.   "subdomain.example.com" is a fully qualified domain name, but "subodmain" is only a partially qualified domain (it needs the context of example.com to resolve).  The trailing dot make is unambiguous that the domain name is fully qualified, but it is not needed in all contexts.  See [Fully qualified domain name - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name)

Comment: @Stephen: my understanding of the terminology is that if there's no trailing dot then it's not an FQDN, but in any case -- in my query, all the components are there except the trailing dot.

Comment: Since both the "Question" and "Authority" portions change whether or not they are using the trailing dot, it could be client that is causing the difference.   What client are you using and with what configuration and arguments?

Comment: @Stephen: there's no special client; it's just a script sending this query periodically via a plain HTTP request (DoH). It's been sending the same request for months; I haven't touched anything this whole time. And Google hasn't been returning a different response either; it's only CloudFlare that's doing this, and it's been going on over the last 24h or so.

Comment: So what is the relevant portion of the script?  Using what HTTP libraries? Which cloudflare server does it contact?  How does it choose which DNS server to contact?  Does it look up the NS records?

Comment: It is not DoH: DoH replies are not in JSON. It is a specific protocol that is some kind of DNS over some kind of HTTP.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller, Patrick: okay I guess I must be mistaken about the name being DoH, but I'm literally just sending a GET request (Accept: application/dns-json) to `https://cloudflare-dns.com/dns-query?name=subdomain.example.com&type=CNAME` and looking at the result. (This also happens for some other types, like NS. Not sure if it happens for every record type.) The response usually has the trailing dot in the question despite the fact that I don't include it, but as I said, recently CloudFlare been oscillating between including and not including it.